# taking javascript into an external file and calling a function from it

Tags: javascript

I have made a working webpage but when i try to take the jscript into an external file it no longer is called. i have put in the code in my header to include the file name but still unable to call it. Here is my jscript please help me out
    by the way just a quick edit I got the isMobile function from here http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2011/11/detecting-mobile-devices-with-javascript/

```
<script>        
    var isMobile = {
      Android: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
      },
      BlackBerry: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
      },
      iOS: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
      },
      Opera: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
      },
      Windows: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
      },
      any: function() {
        return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());
      }
    };
    function load()
    {
      var w=((screen.availWidth)/50)*49;
      var h=(w/4)*3;
      if( isMobile.any() ){
        var t=w;
        w=h;
        h=t;

      }
      var a=document.getElementById('banner');
      a.style.width=w+'px';
      a.style.height=(h/4)+'px';
      var b=document.getElementById('main');
      b.style.width=w+'px';
      b.style.height=Math.round((h/7)*4)+'px';
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: How have you referenced this in your header? Is this the contents of the external file? If so, there should be no `<script>` tag surrounding the JavaScript code.

Comment: yes it is the external file and i put this in my header <script language="JavaScript" src="somejs.js">
</script>

Comment: As far as I am aware, the 'language' attribute is deprecated, use "type='text/javascript'" instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When referencing an external JavaScript file, its contents should not be surrounded by a `<script>` tag.  The `<script>` tag in the main file is what informs the browser that the contents should be parsed as JavaScript.   Remove the surrounding `<script>` tag from the external file.

Proper reference in the main file:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='path/to/external.js'></script>
```

The `language='JavaScript'` attribute [has been deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html) and is unnecessary. You may include `type='text/javascript'`.

The contents of the external file should contain *only* JavaScript code, not surrounding `<script>` tags as in:

```
// File external.js
alert('Look, no script tag!');
```

Comment: Thanks for the help having <script type='text/javascript'> in my external file was the one causing the issue